# Does the sequence of mantra matter for HRIH and HUM?

Tags: mantras, dharma

Looking to seasoned mantra practitioners to provide your kind perspective on this. Thanks in advance.

Energetically speaking is the mantra beeja sequence "HRIH HUM SVAHA" same as "HUM HRIH SVAHA"? If not, please describe how the expected effect would be different.

From my research so far:

- HRIH: power of attraction
- HUM: power of subjugation